# Modelbuilder: How to use submodel output as input for another tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have a simple model that adds some new fields to a layer and calculates values for them. I want to then use this updated layer as an input for Clip. Normally I can just connect the output to the Clip tool, but I would like to package the first part as a submodel:
[image]

When I add the submodel as a tool, the green output variable doesn't show up. Why?

I tried adding Collect Values to the end of the submodel and then setting the output as a parameter. This makes the output variable show up in the main model, but it cannot be connected to Clip as an input; only a precondition. 
[image]

Comment: Oh man, I feel like an idiot now.. my actual submodel had many more "select by attribute and calculate field" commands, and I didn't think that selecting any one of the output variables to make a parameter would work. I was afraid that the tool would move onto the next step without completing the submodel. Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the sub-model, and then choose a variable from that model to expose as a parameter. Like so: [image]. Then inset the sub-model with the exposed parameter into the new model, and the output value (green oval) should be exposed for you to attach further tools to.

Comment: Answers should be more than a single sentence.  Add some more explanation.  As without it, it gets flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Make your output from the submodel a Model Parameter without using Collect Values, then you should be able to connect the output to the Clip tool in your main model.